# Is there a way to see what games contribute to my Avg. Completion Rate?

Tags: steam, achievements

My average completion rate is kinda low, and I wanted to get it a little bit higher. The thing is, I have no idea what games are contributing to my average percentage (minus a few I've played recently) and more importantly, how much they contribute (I want to see a percentage, as well as the number of achievements I have vs. how many there are).

Is there a tool that does this already? I looked at [astats](http://astats.astats.nl/astats/) but it doesn't seem to provide anything like this -- at least not on the surface.

Comment: I've heard that every game you have at least one achievement in counts for the average count. I have no idea if it counts the total percentages per game (for example: a game with 10% achievements done, and one with 90% would give 50% average completion rate) or if it counts the total achievements (game with 100/1000 achievements done and a game with 9/10 achievements done would give 10.7% average completion rate). I also have no written source about what counts and what doesn't.

Comment: @UnknownZombie Yes, that's correct. I'm just interested in boosting the percentage, which is why I want to see what games are contributing, what their % completion is, and how many achievements they have total. Obviously, lower total achievements would be easier to boost the percentage because there are less to get.

Comment: @Arperum what you said is correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've written a script to solve this problem. It can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/seiyria/steam-avg-pct-cli). **If you are not a developer, please use the website above!**

It tells you what games are below average, and which ones are the easiest to boost (strictly mathematically). Improvements and pull requests are welcome. I know very few people will want to download something for this, but it's the best I can do without having a server. Here's a sample run of the code:

```
$ node index.js --api-key=XXX --vanity-url=seiyria
Resolving vanity url "seiyria"...
Getting games for steam64id: 76561197998412147...
Found games: 416 (not all of these will count)
Found 95 games that count for Avg. Completion Rate, sorting...

Your average percent: 29%

Games below the average (sorted by easiest to boost, numerically):
                                Adventures of Shuggy: 3/13      23.08%
                                              Monaco: 2/13      15.38%
                                     Worms Clan Wars: 3/14      21.43%
                                       Tower of Guns: 4/17      23.53%
                                      Frozen Synapse: 2/16      12.50%
                                             Rochard: 3/18      16.67%
                                      Dungeon Hearts: 2/17      11.76%
                                        Lost Marbles: 2/17      11.76%
                                                Cogs: 1/18      5.56%
                                              Wizorb: 2/20      10.00%
                             Scribblenauts Unlimited: 4/25      16.00%
                                    Puzzle Dimension: 3/25      12.00%
                                Legends of Aethereus: 1/23      4.35%
                                             Shatter: 7/30      23.33%
                              Stealth Bastard Deluxe: 4/27      14.81%
                                   Tiny Barbarian DX: 4/27      14.81%
                                            Dwarfs!?: 5/29      17.24%
                                    Orcs Must Die! 2: 3/27      11.11%
                            Crypt of the NecroDancer: 2/28      7.14%
                                 Wanderlust: Rebirth: 3/30      10.00%
                                           Foul Play: 3/30      10.00%
                                          I am Bread: 8/35      22.86%
                                               Trine: 4/33      12.12%
                                        Pixel Piracy: 1/30      3.33%
                                  Blocks That Matter: 1/32      3.13%
Half Minute Hero: Super Mega Neo Climax Ultimate Boy: 3/35      8.57%
                                 Runespell: Overture: 1/35      2.86%
                                          Tower Wars: 1/35      2.86%
                                       Hotline Miami: 1/35      2.86%
                                         Hammerwatch: 4/40      10.00%
                                Atom Zombie Smasher : 4/41      9.76%
                                        Just Cause 2: 12/50     24.00%
                                          Gauntlet™ : 5/43      11.63%
                                          Hero Siege: 9/51      17.65%
                                      Sleeping Dogs™: 16/59     27.12%
                                      Super Meat Boy: 4/48      8.33%
                                              KRUNCH: 4/51      7.84%
                                     One Way Heroics: 11/59     18.64%
                                       Darksiders II: 1/50      2.00%
                                          Torchlight: 16/66     24.24%
                                         Alien Swarm: 15/66     22.73%
                                         Left 4 Dead: 15/73     20.55%
                                      Worms Reloaded: 1/61      1.64%
                                         Beat Hazard: 1/63      1.59%
                                             Magicka: 25/88     28.41%
                                         Rhythm Zone: 10/80     12.50%
                               Saints Row: The Third: 3/83      3.61%
                                The Binding of Isaac: 2/99      2.02%
                                             Sanctum: 1/100     1.00%
                                                Reus: 16/123    13.01%
                                               HOARD: 9/129     6.98%
                             A Valley Without Wind 2: 1/210     0.48%
                          Sid Meier's Civilization V: 34/287    11.85%
                                       Killing Floor: 21/285    7.37%

Games above (or at) the average (sorted by easiest to boost, numerically):
                                             bit Dungeon II: 13/15     86.67%
                                                  Eversion : 11/14     78.57%
                                                        140: 3/6       50.00%
                                           Cities: Skylines: 29/33     87.88%
                             Grotesque Tactics: Evil Heroes: 4/10      40.00%
                                                  Papo & Yo: 4/10      40.00%
                                               Rogue Legacy: 21/28     75.00%
                                                    Nidhogg: 5/12      41.67%
                                                       Pid : 4/12      33.33%
                                                     Portal: 6/15      40.00%
                                                      Chime: 6/15      40.00%
                                                  DLC Quest: 13/22     59.09%
                                        TowerFall Ascension: 20/29     68.97%
                                    Vertical Drop Heroes HD: 19/30     63.33%
                                             SteamWorld Dig: 12/24     50.00%
                                                    Bastion: 9/24      37.50%
                                        Pillars of Eternity: 16/31     51.61%
BIT.TRIP Presents... Runner2: Future Legend of Rhythm Alien: 10/26     38.46%
                                          Quantum Conundrum: 8/25      32.00%
                                          Mark of the Ninja: 21/38     55.26%
                             Super Puzzle Platformer Deluxe: 27/44     61.36%
                                              Shovel Knight: 27/45     60.00%
                                                  La-Mulana: 44/64     68.75%
                                                 Transistor: 10/33     30.30%
                                                      Thief: 13/37     35.14%
                                                   Portal 2: 26/51     50.98%
                                             State of Decay: 20/46     43.48%
                                                   Gunpoint: 15/42     35.71%
                                                 Dishonored: 51/80     63.75%
                                             Goat Simulator: 58/87     66.67%
                                          Dungeon Defenders: 73/104    70.19%
                                              Borderlands 2: 33/69     47.83%
                                                Borderlands: 33/80     41.25%
                                              Left 4 Dead 2: 22/70     31.43%
                                              Torchlight II: 70/119    58.82%
                                Defense Grid: The Awakening: 35/87     40.23%
                                      A Valley Without Wind: 32/98     32.65%
                                                    Trine 2: 30/97     30.93%
                                            Team Fortress 2: 156/513   30.41%
```

Comment: I did something similar: https://github.com/chicks-net/life-graphs/blob/master/Dash/steam_achievements.md

Comment: @chicks That's neat! Much more in-depth than mine.

Comment: Thanks, plus all the code (plus my data) is in that github.  You can do it all without an API key.

Comment: @chicks An API key was a much more convenient solution to the problem IMO. Definitely can be done without but I wanted to keep development time as short as possible.

Comment: I agree the API is more convenient, but if you don't want to live within the limitations of the their licensing it is nice to have another option.  I also maintain history, make graphs, and provide links to the Steam page so you can see what achievements are left do do.  If I had known about the API when I started I would have used it for more.

Comment: Does the online tool still work, or did the API key expire or something?

Comment: @OrangeDog actually, it looks like my entire backend for it disappeared. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Third party websites like the one Seiyria made are great, but do not take into account the games you played during free weekends, and probably also miss games you played using Steam Family Sharing.

If your Steam level is 10 or above, you can see an exact list of games that contribute to your Avg. Game Completion Rate using the Achievement Showcase. While selecting an achievement to display, Steam shows a dropdown input that contains all games you have earned at least 1 achievement for, **including** games you don't actually own. (free weekend games, family sharing, maybe even refunds)

Comment: I believe the Steam API does give you information based on those achievements. Otherwise, I don't think they would do it either - I'm pretty sure they use their own API.

Comment: @Seiyria I thought so too but your website and others say my average is 60%, while Steam displays 57%. After poking around with Steam's API I found out 10 games are missing, which I played years ago in free weekends (and probably earned achievements in them). The dropdown input I mentioned does include these games.

Answer (score 2):

https://completionist.me provides an excellent and extremely easy-to-view bar graph on the right side of your profile showing how many games you have in each bracket of percentage completion (my chart):

[image: cme bar chart - number of games by percent complete]

Above, you can see that I have 984 games with 100% achievements and 12 games with 0-5% completion.  You are able to click into each bar to dive down into which specific games from your Steam account fall within that range of completion (my 5-10% games):

[image]

If you are missing certain free weekend or removed/refunded games, cme provides a recovery process: https://completionist.me/steam/recover

Source: 100Pals Official Achievement Hunter Community: https://www.discord.me/100Pals